# Two way IPSec tunneling

Tags: cisco, router, vpn, ipsec, tunnel

I would like to implement two VPNs on the same interface of a router.

[image]

The router in question is router A which has one public interface Fa0/0 with IP: 22.33.44.55 (ex).

First IPSec tunnel is a LAN-to-LAN IPSec to the peer router B: Fa0/1 with IP: 2.3.4.5

The second IPSec tunnel is to cisco VPN Client, these clients use a public router to connect to internet.

The scenario is like this:  Client connected to router C will use cisco VPN client to connect to the router A and this router will forward the request to router B using IPSec tunnel.

Thanks.

BR

Comment: What you are asking to do is called "hairpinning," and there are many examples on Cisco's website.  The configuration will depend on the IOS version you are running.  I assume your VPN clients also need to get to internal hosts on router A?

Comment: This does not describe hairpinning.

Comment: I just need to connect to router B subnet using vpn client but through router A, please confirm it is hairpinning so I can look for tuto...thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, I hope now it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is possible and has been configured countless times.  Simply look up the commands to configure your networking equipment.  Since you mention Cisco's VPN client, I assume you are using Cisco routers and Cisco Anyconnect VPN Client.

First, configure the Site-to-Site (or LAN-to-LAN) VPN tunnel between A & B.  Then configure the Remote Access VPN service on A.

Comment: The routing betwwen the VPNs is done by the router A??? What needs to be check to make sure router A will forward packets to subnet router B??? Thanks

Comment: Precisely.  Yes.  The routing table determines where the packets are forwarded.